# How can I fill a .JAR file with dependencies in order to set up Wiremock? Current .JAR file size is 20kb, while it should be around 11000kb +

Tags: maven, github, pom.xml, wiremock

I am trying to upgrade the version of Wiremock to 2.35.0 in order to avoid security vulnerabilities.

In order to do this I updated the existing dependencies and wiremock itself in the known `.POM.xml` file.
When running the command `mvn -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true install -DskipTests` in Command Prompt, there comes a `wiremock-body-transformer.jar` file out of it, but the file size is way too small compared to what it was with the previous version (2.17.0).
It seems to be that it doesn't get filled with dependencies.

Below the code that is being used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.*****.wiremock</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock-body-transformer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Wiremock Body Transformer</name>
    <description>A Wiremock extensions to transform the response body, http request call back and additional admin API.</description>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>*****</name>
            <organization>*****</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://www.*****.com/</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>


    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com/opentable/wiremock-body-transformer.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:opentable/wiremock-body-transformer.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/opentable/wiremock-body-transformer.git</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                <archive>
                <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock-jre8-standalone -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.35.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tests dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Would love to hear from you guys on what should be changed in order for it to work.

P.S. I am no coding guru so it would help if you could mention where exactly a code addition/change would need to be within the .pom file.

I tried updating the dependencies in the .POM file in order to upgrade to 2.35.0 but no success so far.
Also tried the standard Wiremock version 2.35.0 instead of the standalone version, but no luck. Still resulted in a 20kb .JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

Your Maven assembly plugin configuration seems... not linked to the maven execution phases.

You might need to properly configure the `maven-assembly-plugin` (using its [latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin)), to create a JAR with all the dependencies included.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version> <!-- Add the version -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- Add this line to bind the execution to the package phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal> <!-- Add this line to use the 'single' goal of the plugin -->
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It should bind the plugin execution to the `package` phase and uses the '`single`' goal to create a single JAR with all the dependencies.

Replace the existing maven-assembly-plugin configuration in your `pom.xml` with the updated configuration, and then run the same Maven command as before:

```
mvn -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true install -DskipTests
```

Check if that does create a JAR file with the expected size, including all the dependencies.

---

The error message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project wiremock-body-transformer: compilation failure: 
Compilation failure: location of the bodytransformer.java file cannot find symbol symbol: class WiremockHelpers 
another same 
cannot find symbol error but with symbol: variable WiremockHelpers another same 
cannot find symbol error but with symbol: class WiremockHelpers as well.
```

I see in the jar file ([`wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.35.0.jar`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock-jre8-standalone/2.35.0/wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.35.0.jar))

```
com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/extension/responsetemplating/helpers/WireMockHelpers.class
```

Your import `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.helpers.WiremockHelpers;` seems therefore correct

Since the import is correct, double-check your dependencies with the output of `mvn dependency:tree`.